# Create a procedure to copy some records from a table to another

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a simple procedure to copy some records from Table1 to Table2.

```
Table1:
id number PK
operation varchar2(50)
position varchar2(50)
code_operation varchar2(50) FK

Table2:
code_operation varchar2(50) PK
operation varchar2(50)
position varchar2(50)
client_number varchar2(50)
```

Starting from the `client_number` I have to copy the associated `operation` and `position` from Table1 and insert into `operation` and `position` of Table2.
I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_DATA(
BEGIN
    DECLARE P_CLIENT_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50);
    DECLARE P_CODE_OPERATION VARCHAR2(50);
    DECLARE P_DIVISION VARCHAR2(50);
    DECLARE P_POSITION VARCHAR2(50)

    SELECT CODE_OPERATION INTO P_CODE_OPERATION FROM TABLE2;
    SELECT CLIENT_NUMBER INTO P_CLIENT_NUMBER FROM TABLE2;                
    SELECT DIVISION INTO P_DIVISION FROM TABLE1;
    SELECT POSITION INTO P_POSITION FROM TABLE1;
    INSERT INTO TABLE2(DIVISION,POSITION)
    WHERE CODE_OPERATION=P_COD_OPERATION;
END
);
```

I've got this error `ERROR PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “DECLARE”` but I don't understand why, plus with this error I don't know if my code is correct or not.

Comment: If this is a parent-child table (as the FK suggests) then what is the point of duplicating so much data in both tables?  That, in itself, appears to be a  flaw in the application design.

Comment: Besides being a bad design, you could do in a one liner without variables by running ```INSERT INTO target_table(target_fields) SELECT source_fields FROM source_table```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you got is easy to fix. PL/SQL block has `declare-begin-exception-end` structure, which means that you first declare variables (in a stored procedure, you don't use `declare` keyword; strange enough, for triggers - which as kind of *stored* as well - you do use it). For example:

```
create or replace procedure copy_data as
  p_client_number   table2.client_number%type;
begin
  select client_number  
    into p_client_number  
    from table2;                
exception
  when too_many_rows then
    raise;
end;
```

However, without `WHERE` clause (or an aggregate, such as `MIN` or `MAX`), this will raise `too_many_rows` exception because it'll try to fetch all client numbers into a scalar variable, and that won't work. I included the way which shows *how* to handle it. What will you really do? Restrict number of rows to `1`. Similarly, you'd handle `no_data_found` or other exceptions.

---

What you described looks strange to me.

- you want to insert into `table2` - which is a *master* table
- values you'd insert are in `table1` - which is a *detail* table

Looking at tables, I'd say that it should be vice versa.

```
insert into table1 (id, operation, position, code_operation)
  select seq.nextval,
         b.operation,
         b.position,
         b.code_operation
  from table2 b
  where b.client_number = 'ABC';
```

(I presumed that primary key is populated via a sequence.)

---

It also means that none of variables you declared is necessary. But, the procedure would accept client number as a parameter.

The whole procedure would then be:

```
create or replace procedure copy_data
  (par_client_number in table2.client_number%type)
is
begin
  insert into table1 (id, operation, position, code_operation)
      select seq.nextval,
             b.operation,
             b.position,
             b.code_operation
      from table2 b
      where b.client_number = par_client_number;
end;
```

You'd call it as

```
begin
  copy_data('ABC');
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the whole explanation. I've much to learn :)